# How to extract the label text from the checkboxlist?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running some selenium tests and am checking to make sure that the correct boxes have been checked.

```
String curConfig2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MainContent_ConfigCheckBoxList_6")).GetAttribute("value");
Assert.AreEqual("RH7", curConfig2);
```

Is what I currently have, but unfortunately the value and the label are not the same. Here is the information about this specific checkbox:

```
<td>
     <input id="MainContent_ConfigCheckBoxList_6" name="ctl00$MainContent$ConfigCheckBoxList$6" checked="checked" value="OS" type="checkbox">
     <label for="MainContent_ConfigCheckBoxList_6">RH7</label>
</td>
```

Again, I just want to be able to extract the value "RH7" from the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `<input>` `checked` attribute and then check the sibling `<label>` text

```
string locatorString = "MainContent_ConfigCheckBoxList_6";
string curConfig2 = driver.FindElement(By.Id(locatorString)).GetAttribute("checked");
string name = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[for='" + locatorString + "']")).Text;

Assert.AreEqual(curConfig2, "checked");
Assert.AreEqual(name, "RH7");
```